# PHP/DNS Catch all email

Tags: php, email, dns, pipe, cpanel

Is there a method of catching emails sent to my domain. I am aware of catch all using cPanel and PHP however I want to do the following:

"subscriber@somewhere.com.mydomain.com"

As you can see from above, the email comprises of an email address ("subscriber@somewhere.com") prepended on to .mydomain.com

However, when i test this I get a lookup dns error on my mail client.

Any suggestions how to catch email sent using the email format above?

The script below is one I have found for a PHP catchall.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

$email = '';

while(!feof($fd))
{
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}

fclose($fd);
mail('reciever@mydomain.com', 'test', $email);
?>
```

Comment: You want a *wildcard MX record*

Comment: If you own the `mydomain.com` domain then you could add a catch-all (wildcard) `MX` DNS record to catch all emails to all your sub-domains

Comment: @AeroX shouldn't the sub domain exist then?

Comment: @BartFriederichs With a catch-all (wildcard) MX record the sub-domains would't have to actually exist

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MX records can contain wildcards:

https://serverfault.com/questions/405639/wildcard-for-a-and-mx-records-possible

So, assuming you own mydomain.com, set up a wildcard MX record.